# Condition for $f-\frac{A}{z-a}-\frac{B}{z-b}-\frac{C}{z-c}$ to have primitive

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $D_a=\{|z-a| \leq r_a\}$ and $D_b, D_c$ defined similarly such that they are disjoint. Suppose $f$ is analytic in $U=\mathbb{C} \setminus (D_a\cup D_b\cup D_c)$. Prove that there are constant $A,B,C$ such that $f-\dfrac{A}{z-a}-\dfrac{B}{z-b}-\dfrac{C}{z-c}$ have primitive.

Actually, what theorem guarantee that a function have primitive in a domain which is not simply? I guess the answer should be the residue of $f$ at the centre of the balls

I am trying to construct the primitive, let $z_0 \in U$ then there is a ball $B_r(z_0) \subset U$. Then I pick $a,z \in B_r(z_0)$ to form a triangle and follow the argument by Morera's theorem, then I can construct the primitive. Seems that i do not have any constraint in $A,B,C$. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should help you provide a solution to your problem.

Let $f : U\to \mathbb C$ be meromorphic, and pick a point $c\in U$ that is an isolated singulatiry. Take $B\subseteq U$ an open ball around $c$ with closure in $B$ so that $c$ is the only singularity of $f$ in $B$. Then I claim that

> The number $\lambda = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B} f dz$ is unique among those numbers such that $f - \dfrac{\lambda}{z-c}$ admits a primitive in a neighborhood of $c$.

To see this, let $f=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \lambda_n (z-c)^n$ be the Laurent expansion of $f$ around $c$. Then $\lambda = \lambda_{-1}$, so if this number 
vanishes, one can integate $f$ term by term to obtain a primitive around $c$. Conversely, if $f$ is integrable around $c$, integrating  $f-\lambda(z-c)^{-1}$ around a small circle centered at $c$ gives $0=\lambda_{-1}-\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But i am still confused what wrong in my trial and Morera's theorem

Comment: @mnmn1993 Since you have given no details as to what you're doing, I cannot really pinpoint your mistake. :)

Comment: So sorry about that. Let $z_0 \in U$ then there is a ball $B_r(z_0) \subset U$. Then I pick $a,z \in B_r(z_0)$ to form a triangle $T$. Since $g=f-\dfrac{A}{z-a}-\dfrac{B}{z-b}-\dfrac{C}{z-c}$ is analytic in $B_r(z_0)$, so $\int_T g =0$.Define $F(z)=\int_{a}^z g $(where the integration is taken along the line segment from $a$ to $z$), then $\int_{a}^z g+\int_{z_0}^a g=\int_{z_0}^z g$ which implies $\dfrac{F(z)-F(z_0)}{z-z_0} -g(z_0)=\dfrac{1}{z-z_0}\int_{z_0}^z g-g(z_0)$. By taking $z \rightarrow z_0$, I have constructed the primitive.

Comment: @mnmn1993 That integral is not zero.

Comment: Why? Because I think that $B_r(z_0)$ doesn't contain $a,b,c$ and $\int_T g=0$ since $g$ is analytic in  $B_r(z_0)$.

Comment: @mnmn1993 You need that $\int_T gdz=0$ for *any* triangle, not whichever triangle you choose.

Comment: Is it true that if a function $f$ is analytic inside a open connented set $U$，then for any closed rectifiable curve $\gamma$ inside $U$，we have $\int_{\gamma}f =0$?